# Stuck at login screen in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, login, login-screen

When I've start my system, Ubuntu 14.04, my login screen got stuck, with mouse cursor in middle of the screen. However, sometimes system allow me to enter my credential but the results are same and nothing appeared. After reading [1](http://jiakaizhang.com/fix-frozen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04/), [2](http://itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04/), I've tried to enter in terminal after pressing Ctrl + Alt + F2, but nothing happened and the same screen is appearing. I've attached the screen image below. 
 
 I'm using Lenovo Thinkpad E520.

 
[image] 

 
 
I need your help for this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I mean no offence but... Did you try restarting your system?
(Also, the two topics are about screen freezing AFTER login, you didn't mention login before your screen froze.)

Comment: 1- I've restart my system many time, nothing happened.
2- Yes, sometimes system allow me to enter my credential but the results are same. -- @Kotshi

Comment: I've got one suggestion but you might wait for other peoples opinions before trying: If you're using grub, put your cursor on ubuntu then press e to edit. Go to the line starting with "linux" and add `init=/bin/bash`` at the end. Press f10 to boot and you should get a root terminal. Then, try resetting your password or uninstalling/reinstalling your graphical interface.

I forgot to ask: did you make changes on your system lately?

Comment: I've pressed 'e' as you said for 'edit' but nothing happened? I've made no changes other than installing updates.

Comment: What version of grub are you using?

Comment: When your cursor is on Ubuntu inside grub, what is written at the botton om the screen?

Comment: grub version 2.02~beta2-9 - @Kotshi

Comment: When you're in grub, don't you see somethin like "press e to edit" at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Yes, I've enter in the edit screen, but there is no line starting with "linux". What can I do now?

Comment: Really? On ubuntu 14.04, it's supposed to look like this http://linuxconfig.org/images/ubuntu_14.4_password_recover.png

Comment: Yes, there is no line starting with linux.  This is on this screen;  fi  parttool ${root} hidden-  drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}  chainloader +1

Comment: This is strange, was your cursor on ubuntu when you pressed 'e' ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey try resetting your display device manager.

Go to terminal first **ctrl +alt+f2**

check default display manager

`cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`

restart a display manager:

`sudo restart display_manager`

e.g.:

`sudo restart lightdm`

It may help.